# How to put rounded corners on a MUI X charts Bar chart?

Tags: reactjs, svg, charts, rounded-corners, mui-x-charts

I have created a chart using MUI X barchart,

```
import { BarChart } from '@mui/x-charts/BarChart';
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme, useTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
```

and I want to give the bars rounded corners.  I tried borderRadius for sx property and series property. but it didn't work. the sx property creates a border around the chart not for every bar.
I have the following code so far:

```
 <ThemeProvider theme={darkTheme}  >
    <BarChart
       
        sx={[{p: 5, border: 1, borderRadius: 3}]}
        yAxis={[
              {
               id: 'barCategories',
               data: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
               scaleType: 'band',
              },
         ]}
         series={[
                {
                 data: [50, 20, 85, 60, 20],
                 color: '#fff',
                },
                            
          ]}
          layout="horizontal"
     />
</ThemeProvider>
```

and it looks like this:
[image]

How can I make the bars looks rounded corners like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the underlying bar element for [MUI Bar Chart](https://mui.com/x/react-charts) is an [SVG rect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/rect) element, you will not be able to apply [CSS `border-radius`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius). But you can provide your own custom [`Bar` component](https://mui.com/x/react-charts/bars/) that, instead of rendering a `rect` element, renders a [`path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/path) element appearing as a rectangle with rounded corners<sup>1</sup> and pass that component via the `slots` prop.

For example:

```
<BarChart
  ...
  layout="horizontal"
  slots={{
    bar: (props) => {
      const radius = 7;
      const {x, y, height, width, ownerState, ...restProps} = props
      
      // Path of a rectangle with rounded corners on the right
      // for horizontal layout
      const d = `M${x},${y} h${width - radius} a${radius},${radius} 0 0 1 ${radius},${radius}v ${height - 2 * radius} a${radius},${radius} 0 0 1 ${-radius},${radius} h${radius - width}z`
      return <path d={d} fill={ownerState.color}
      {...restProps} />
    }
  }}
    />
```

Which produces:

[image: example bar chart with rounded corners]

*(I would memo this for better performance -- this demo is just to get you rolling.)*

**Working CodeSanbox:** https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-bar-chart-with-rounded-corders-right-zms2m5?file=/Demo.js

<sup>1</sup> You could also create a component that still uses a `rect` and provide a [`clipPath`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath) for the rounded corners, but IMO this is the simpler option.

References:

- [`BarPlotSlotComponentProps`](https://github.com/mui/mui-x/blob/master/packages/x-charts/src/BarChart/BarPlot.tsx#L44)

Comment: wow, this is amazing. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome @Maria!

Answer (score 1):

Steve's response didnt work correctly for me so what I did is passed the same Slot prop into the Barchart Component. 

I was not getting the response thorugh destructring so I had to convert it to string and then parse it again. (it is not a good practise, But if it is necessary make a commons folder and define the logic separately and pass it here as a function)

```
`<barChart
//Your other props

    slots={{
              bar: (props) => {
                const { style } = props;
                const str = JSON.stringify(style);
                const arr = JSON.parse(str);
                const { x, y, height, width } = arr;
    
                let radius = width;
            
                const d = `M${x},${y} h${width - radius} a${radius},${radius} 0 0 1 ${radius},${radius}v ${height - 2 * radius} a${radius},${radius} 0 0 1 ${-radius},${radius} h${radius - width}z`
                return <path d={d}></path>;
              },
            }}
           />`
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).